# Debian 11: Can't install package libnorm1

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

When I am trying to update all packages on my Debian 11 I am getting this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnorm1_1.5.9+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: What's the command you used, and what is the full message?

Comment: I don't remember. This problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dpkg` with `--force-overwrite` option:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libnorm1_1.5.9+dfsg-2_amd64
sudo apt install -f
```